# Discord Webhook sending multiple messages when given input from TextBox

Tags: lua, discord, webhooks, roblox

Basically, I have a script in a roblox game which gets text input, a script to put this input through a filter, and a script to send this input to the webhook, however it is being sent multiple times, which increases with every message. Is there any way to fix this?

LocalScript:

```
local rem = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Server")
local rem2 = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Client")
local TextService = game:GetService("TextService")
local textbox = game.Workspace:WaitForChild("Part").SurfaceGui.TextBox
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local userid = player.UserId
local filter1 = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("FilterServer")
local filter2 = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("FilterClient")
local filter3 = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("FilteredBAD")
local earlymessage = ""
local message = ""

textbox.FocusLost:Connect(function(inputObj)
    earlymessage = textbox.Text
    print(userid)
    tostring(earlymessage)
    print(earlymessage)
    filter1:FireServer(earlymessage)
    filter2.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(msg)
        message = msg
        rem2:FireServer(message)
        wait(3)
    end)
end)

filter3.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(text)
    textbox.Text = text
end)
```

Filter Script:

```
local rem = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("FilterServer")
local rem2 = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("FilterClient")
local rem3 = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("FilteredBAD")
local TextService = game:GetService("TextService")
local finalmessage = ""
local cooldown = false

rem.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, startmessage)
    if cooldown == false then
        local success, errorMessage = pcall(function()
            tostring(startmessage)
            local userid = player.UserId
            finalmessage = TextService:FilterStringAsync(tostring(startmessage),     userid):GetNonChatStringForBroadcastAsync()
            rem3:FireAllClients(finalmessage)
            tostring(finalmessage)
            rem2:FireClient(player, finalmessage)
            print(finalmessage)
            cooldown = true
            wait(4)
            cooldown = false
        end)
        if not success then
            warn("Error filtering text:", errorMessage)
            rem3:FireAllClients()
        end
    end
end)
```

Message send script:

```
local http = game:GetService("HttpService")
local cooldown = false
local rem1 = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Server")
local rem2 = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Client")

script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Send.SendGui.TextButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if cooldown == false then
        rem1:FireAllClients()
        print("client fired")
        rem2.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, message)
                print(message)
            local Data = {
                ["content"] = message
            }
            Data = http:JSONEncode(Data)
            print(Data)
                http:PostAsync("https://webhook.lewisakura.moe/api/webhooks/keygerekiki", Data)
            cooldown = true
            wait(3)
            cooldown = false
        end)
    end
end)
```

I have been trying for hours to fix this with no help. I expect it to only send one message, and it only does that the first message, then keeps increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're connecting more event  handlers whenever you receive either a FocusLost or mouse click. So, yeah, that'll just increase over time.